# Jquery on change function not working

Tags: jquery, onchange

My `jquery` on change function not working.

How to create on change function?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select[name='UF_CRM_1520054293']").on('change',function () {

        $("select[name='UF_CRM_1520054676']").empty();

        var selected_type = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
                url: "//<?echo $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];?>/services/request.php",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                data: {selected_type : selected_type},
                success: function(data){
                        //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                        $("select[name='UF_CRM_1520054676']")
                            .append('<option value=' + 0 + '>' +'Select Location' + '</option>');   
                        $.each(data, function(k,v)
                        {
                            $("select[name='UF_CRM_1520054676']")
                                .append('<option value=' + v.ID + '>' + v.LOCATION + '</option>');
                        });
                }
        }); 
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hfwm86h6/6/)

Comment: Why are you doing `$("select[name='UF_CRM_1520054676']").empty();
`?

Comment: removing all option of that drop-down

Comment: please share the fiddle? It will be easy to edit and update @TUSH

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hfwm86h6/6/

Comment: Please note I cant change the HTML code provided in fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('change',"select[name='UF_CRM_1520054293']",function () {
$("select[name='UF_CRM_1520054676']").empty();

var selected_type = $(this).val();
$.ajax({

    url: "//<?echo $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];?>/services/request.php",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    data: {selected_type : selected_type},
    success: function(data){
    //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    $("select[name='UF_CRM_1520054676']").append('<option value=' + 0 + '>' +'Select Location' + '</option>');  
    $.each(data,function(k,v)
            {
                $("select[name='UF_CRM_1520054676']").append('<option value=' + v.ID + '>' + v.LOCATION + '</option>');
            });


            }
    }); 
});
});
```

You should provide a selector to the `on` function.

for more info

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Glad to help,anytime dud

Answer (score 0):

So the ideal place to clear the select dropdown will be insert the ajax success callback just before appending new options.

In your code you wont be able to fetch the value of select as you are clearing it already.

```
$("select[name='UF_CRM_1520054293']").on('change', function() {

  var selected_type = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({

    url: "//<?echo $_SERVER["
    SERVER_NAME "];?>/services/request.php",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      selected_type: selected_type
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $("select[name='UF_CRM_1520054676']").empty();
      $("select[name='UF_CRM_1520054676']").append('<option value=' + 0 + '>' + 'Select Location' + '</option>');
      $.each(data, function(k, v) {
        $("select[name='UF_CRM_1520054676']").append('<option value=' + v.ID + '>' + v.LOCATION + '</option>');
      });


    }
  });
});
```